# serverless express can't retrieve pdf file (base64 encoding)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, pdf, serverless-framework

I have setup an express/serverless application to retrieve a pdf file on a GET request. But I just retrieve a corrupted repsonse pdf response. I just wondering If my settings are correct to achieve a correct response.

I'm using [aws-serverless-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-serverless-express) and want to return my pdf buffer to the client browser (it should open in the browser)

My code:

```
  status = 200;
  let fileName = "demo.pdf"; 
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' + fileName + '"');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('isBase64Encoded', true);//isBase64Encoded: true

  let pdf = pdfBuffer.toString('base64');
  res.status(status).send(pdf);
```

so I'm sending a base64 encoded string to APIGW. I'm not actually sure if I can set the **isBase64Encoded** flag via header. I read this before but I'm not so certain about that

I have done this whole procedure before, but didn't make use of aws-serverless-express (where I Could set the **isBase64Encoded** flag easily)

I'm also using [serverless-apigw-binary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-apigw-binary) to automatically setup APIGW for the correct decoding of the base64 encoded data

Comment: What exactly is your question? What IS happening, and what ISN'T happening that should be?

Comment: hope it's better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda is automatically encoding to base64, so I had to remove it and directly send the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problem while using serverless Express. AWS Gateway needs a http response like this:

```
{
  "header":{....}
  "body": "/9j/4AAQSkZ...",
  "isBase64Encoded": true
}
```

It's useless to put `isBase64Encoded` in the Http Response Header, AWS API Gateway only checks if the `isBase64Encoded` is outside the Http header. If it's true, then decode the body before sending it to a HTTP client.

Express (its response object) doesn't seem to allow to add something outside HTTP Header in a Http Response.

If you don't want to give up using Express, the workaround is to do the decoding in the browser, which is pretty easy:

```
var decodedData = Buffer.from(body,'base64')
```